# How to resize a partition (to make my Ubuntu partition bigger) without losing any data?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I currently dual boot my laptop with Windows and Ubuntu.

Unfortunately when I partitioned my hard drive I did not leave enough room for my Ubuntu partition.

Now it is almost out of space.  Running `df -h` shows the following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            9.6G     0  9.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.0G  1.7M  2.0G   1% /run
/dev/sda6        19G   16G  2.2G  89% /
tmpfs           9.7G   79M  9.6G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           9.7G     0  9.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2       185G  142G   43G  77% /mnt/windows
tmpfs           2.0G   20K  2.0G   1% /run/user/111
tmpfs           2.0G   32K  2.0G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Is it possible for me to shrink the windows partition (`/dev/sda`) and increase the size of my Ubuntu partition (`/dev/sda6`) without losing any data on either?

If so, how do I do this?

Comment: Your Windows partition is just about full. Actually the recommendation is to keep 30% free in a NTFS partition, so it works well. At 10% free you just about cannot do a defrag. You have 23% free and should be noticing Windows running a bit slower. Time for major housecleaning or new larger drive. And you always need really good backups before any major system change like repartitioning.

Comment: +1 to @oldfred's comment. If it were a regular answer, I would upvote it.

Comment: @sudodus I don't think that is a good idea. What he said is a good comment but it does not answer the question which is *how to resize a partition without losing data* not *should resize a partition*.

Comment: Well, according to the title you are right, but according to the question at the end of the text, knowing that the Windows partition is rather full, it should be discouraged to shrink that partition to make it possible to make your Ubuntu partition bigger. - If you want to do it anyway, boot into Windows and shrink its partition, but do *not* create any new partition. After that boot into an Ubuntu live drive (USB or DVD) and use gparted to increase the size of the Ubuntu partition. If you move the head end of that partition, you have to reinstall grub, also do that via the live Ubuntu drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Windows, you could use the `Disk management` utility (search for that term and Windows will propose the `Create and format disk partitions`). From there you can resize NTFS partitions (provided there is sufficient empty space on the disk as pointed out by @oldfred in the above comment).

Another solution which I prefer is to use a `GParted live` image where you can resize any type of partitions. In my opinion, it is probably safer to use this solution as you have mixed partition types.

Comment: Always use Window's Disk Management app to resize NTFS partitions, never gparted. Use gparted to resize ext2-4 partitions.

Comment: I would definitely take a look at oldfred's comment and edit your answer to include a warning about keeping in mind available disk space when editing NTFS partitions